# Can we open 360 photos in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 360-virtual-reality, 360-panorama

I have 360 photos. Can I open it in unity and make it into VR for mobile.If it can be done, please tell me how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code generator, please provide the code/research you have already done. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Yes.  There are any number of kits on the asset store - such as [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/35102) or [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/61067).

Stack Overflow is a place where you should go when you've already worked hard to find an answer, but you've hit some wall you can't seem to quite get over it.  So in the future, please ask broad questions like this one on other forums, such as Reddit.  And, by the way, someone [already has](https://www.reddit.com/r/GearVR/comments/3fasyc/given_a_360_mp4_how_can_i_get_started_with_vr_in/).

You're going to have to figure out what platform you want to build for (Gear VR?  Oculus?  Playstation VR?), what sort of stuff you are rendering (video from a 360 camera?  Photos from a 360 camera?  Or "360" videos or photos stitched together from multiple sources?), and how you'd like to go about implementing it (with a kit?  From scratch?  etc.).

Feel free to come back and ask questions again when you have a more specific technical problem you need help with - that's what Stack Overflow is really for.